# Magento - selecting shipping methods based on product quantity

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Is it possible (specially without changes on source code)? 
Here is the scenario:

If the buyer gets up to 2 units of the same item, shipping for those items will be a flat rate of $17 because I can use a flat rate envelope for that.
If he gets more than 2 units, use the USPS module to calculate the shipping costs.

However, it has to work with selected items only because all others will be using the USPS module.

I'm using Magento 1.7 Community edition.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can afford WebShopApps shipping modules, then that is it http://www.webshopapps.com/row/shipping.html

Comment: Oh man, I wish I could. They have some really great stuff. Thanks anyways.